# alasql plugin not able to download the file in safari browser

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, alasql

I am using alasql plugin to generate and export excel file in javascript. This works fine, but in safari browser in ipad/iphone it does not download any excel and sometimes gives error like cannot download the file. How do i solve this issue in safari?

```
function createexcel(data, excelName) {
                    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("' + excelName + '",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [data]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Safari are you using?

Because Alasql uses fileSaver for downloading files to your system. And Filesaver is not supported for safari 8.0 and hence it doesn't work.